# Live video in facebook is lagging while using ffmpeg from video link

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, video-streaming, video-encoding

Livevideo in facebook is working fine for local device video(case 1) but its having lagging issue from video link(case 2) using FFMPEG.

Please find command for the same and log.

Case 1 - Command : ffmpeg -re -i videoplayback.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f flv "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/5162241770554550?s_bl=1&s_oil=2&s_psm=1&s_sw=0&s_tids=1&s_vt=api-s&a=Aby_ZWutqdUZR26F"

Log -
2022-09-01 18:27:19.683  frame=    9 fps=0.0 q=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=21 drop=0 speed=   0x
2022-09-01 18:27:20.163  frame=   19 fps= 19 q=0.0 q=33.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.44 bitrate=   8.7kbits/s dup=44 drop=0 speed=0.437x
2022-09-01 18:27:20.879  frame=   32 fps= 21 q=0.0 q=33.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.92 bitrate=   4.1kbits/s dup=74 drop=0 speed=0.616x
2022-09-01 18:27:21.374  frame=   47 fps= 22 q=0.0 q=33.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.41 bitrate=   2.7kbits/s dup=109 drop=0 speed=0.651x
2022-09-01 18:27:21.940  frame=   58 fps= 21 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=      40kB time=00:00:01.90 bitrate= 174.2kbits/s dup=135 drop=0 speed=0.703x
2022-09-01 18:27:22.530  frame=   69 fps= 21 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     101kB time=00:00:01.92 bitrate= 429.9kbits/s dup=161 drop=0 speed=0.585x
2022-09-01 18:27:23.003  frame=   83 fps= 22 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     165kB time=00:00:02.39 bitrate= 566.5kbits/s dup=193 drop=0 speed=0.623x
2022-09-01 18:27:23.567  frame=   97 fps= 22 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     235kB time=00:00:02.90 bitrate= 661.9kbits/s dup=226 drop=0 speed=0.667x
2022-09-01 18:27:24.133  frame=  111 fps= 23 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     315kB time=00:00:03.36 bitrate= 765.8kbits/s dup=259 drop=0 speed=0.693x
2022-09-01 18:27:24.715  frame=  125 fps= 23 q=29.0 q=30.0 size=     385kB time=00:00:03.85 bitrate= 817.5kbits/s dup=291 drop=0 speed=0.703x
2022-09-01 18:27:25.227  frame=  142 fps= 24 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     486kB time=00:00:04.83 bitrate= 824.6kbits/s dup=331 drop=0 speed=0.802x
2022-09-01 18:27:25.712  frame=  158 fps= 24 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     563kB time=00:00:05.31 bitrate= 867.6kbits/s dup=368 drop=0 speed=0.811x
2022-09-01 18:27:26.262  frame=  173 fps= 24 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     634kB time=00:00:05.78 bitrate= 897.8kbits/s dup=403 drop=0 speed=0.819x
2022-09-01 18:27:26.796  frame=  191 fps= 25 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     718kB time=00:00:06.24 bitrate= 941.7kbits/s dup=445 drop=0 speed=0.82x
2022-09-01 18:27:27.337  frame=  211 fps= 26 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     806kB time=00:00:07.17 bitrate= 920.7kbits/s dup=492 drop=0 speed=0.882x
2022-09-01 18:27:27.816  frame=  233 fps= 27 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     921kB time=00:00:07.64 bitrate= 987.4kbits/s dup=543 drop=0 speed=0.881x
2022-09-01 18:27:28.348  frame=  251 fps= 27 q=29.0 q=30.0 size=    1031kB time=00:00:08.42 bitrate=1001.9kbits/s dup=585 drop=0 speed=0.919x
2022-09-01 18:27:28.868  frame=  274 fps= 28 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=    1141kB time=00:00:09.03 bitrate=1035.2kbits/s dup=639 drop=0 speed=0.933x
2022-09-01 18:27:29.393  frame=  293 fps= 29 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=    1283kB time=00:00:09.49 bitrate=1106.5kbits/s dup=683 drop=0 speed=0.932x
2022-09-01 18:27:29.870  frame=  313 fps= 29 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=    1433kB time=00:00:10.42 bitrate=1125.6kbits/s dup=730 drop=0 speed=0.975x
2022-09-01 18:27:30.356  frame=  331 fps= 30 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=    1557kB time=00:00:10.89 bitrate=1170.9kbits/s dup=772 drop=0 speed=0.973x
2022-09-01 18:27:30.843  frame=  346 fps= 30 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=    1627kB time=00:00:11.35 bitrate=1174.1kbits/s dup=807 drop=0 speed=0.971x
2022-09-01 18:27:31.357  frame=  361 fps= 30 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=    1711kB time=00:00:11.81 bitrate=1186.2kbits/s dup=842 drop=0 speed=0.969x
2022-09-01 18:27:31.862  frame=  376 fps= 30 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=    1789kB time=00:00:12.28 bitrate=1193.3kbits/s dup=877 drop=0 speed=0.967x
2022-09-01 18:27:32.371  frame=  391 fps= 30 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=    1870kB time=00:00:12.74 bitrate=1201.8kbits/s dup=912 drop=0 speed=0.965x
2022-09-01 18:27:32.908  frame=  406 fps= 30 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=    1959kB time=00:00:13.67 bitrate=1173.3kbits/s dup=947 drop=0 speed=0.997x
2022-09-01 18:27:33.109  frame=  422 fps= 30 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=    2061kB time=00:00:14.14 bitrate=1193.8kbits/s dup=984 drop=0 speed=0.992x

Case 2 - Command : ffmpeg -re -i "https://rr1---sn-o58g5ob-nu8e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1662057728&ei=n6gQY-D9OLSA4-EPzJKYyA0&ip=103.11.117.194&id=o-AOgjPoKU_GiUy425eSSF6tHEIQvoHpsUyyIHnHERk6YS&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=6k&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-o58g5ob-nu8e%2Csn-cvhelnls&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=1&pcm2cms=yes&pl=24&initcwndbps=867500&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&ns=z8jzAKb15xkjMcyG0dBthZQH&ratebypass=yes&dur=256.116&lmt=1649507860591021&mt=1662035606&fvip=3&fexp=24001373%2C24007246&c=WEB&rbqsm=fr&txp=4532434&n=PSC3ywazY86ChDwPP2&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAI-aPoysSukxGNgmlsn-4bgCG84gQnILTkGJR8WQnK_bAiEArwSM0z-GYO4SinkzgdGG5qZJtoiP3ROYneg88sOjhv4%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIhAJb7JQbSPhhH2jte8pE0G0iWf1LtRlEzQgSy-2pBGPg3AiBWX0P27KU2xwazMGLiBaQanUOeytB0jPgFsJleM8DO-w%3D%3D" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f flv "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/5162241770554550?s_bl=1&s_oil=2&s_psm=1&s_sw=0&s_tids=1&s_vt=api-s&a=Aby_ZWutqdUZR26F"

Log -

2022-09-01 18:24:23.080   frame=    9 fps=0.0 q=0.0 q=0.0 size= 0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=21 drop=0 speed=   0x
2022-09-01 18:24:23.579   frame=   23 fps= 22 q=0.0 q=33.0 size= 0kB time=00:00:00.44 bitrate=   8.7kbits/s dup=53 drop=0 speed=0.427x
2022-09-01 18:24:24.177   frame=   33 fps= 21 q=0.0 q=33.0 size= 0kB time=00:00:00.92 bitrate=   4.1kbits/s dup=77 drop=0 speed=0.589x
2022-09-01 18:24:24.872   frame=   39 fps= 18 q=0.0 q=33.0 size= 0kB time=00:00:00.99 bitrate=   3.9kbits/s dup=91 drop=0 speed=0.458x
2022-09-01 18:24:25.513   frame=   46 fps= 16 q=0.0 q=33.0 size= 0kB time=00:00:01.41 bitrate=   2.7kbits/s dup=107 drop=0 speed=0.497x
2022-09-01 18:24:26.070   frame=   52 fps= 15 q=0.0 q=33.0 size= 0kB time=00:00:01.41 bitrate=   2.7kbits/s dup=121 drop=0 speed=0.41x
2022-09-01 18:24:26.602   frame=   58 fps= 14 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=      40kB time=00:00:01.90 bitrate= 174.2kbits/s dup=135 drop=0 speed=0.468x
2022-09-01 18:24:27.341   frame=   63 fps= 14 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=      72kB time=00:00:01.90 bitrate= 311.6kbits/s dup=147 drop=0 speed=0.417x
2022-09-01 18:24:27.957   frame=   71 fps= 13 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     115kB time=00:00:02.39 bitrate= 392.6kbits/s dup=165 drop=0 speed=0.448x
2022-09-01 18:24:28.621   frame=   78 fps= 13 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     141kB time=00:00:02.39 bitrate= 483.2kbits/s dup=182 drop=0 speed=0.409x
2022-09-01 18:24:29.277   frame=   82 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     154kB time=00:00:02.39 bitrate= 527.3kbits/s dup=191 drop=0 speed=0.363x
2022-09-01 18:24:29.851   frame=   89 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     197kB time=00:00:02.87 bitrate= 560.9kbits/s dup=207 drop=0 speed=0.397x
2022-09-01 18:24:30.385   frame=   96 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     233kB time=00:00:02.87 bitrate= 662.2kbits/s dup=224 drop=0 speed=0.371x
2022-09-01 18:24:31.119   frame=  100 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     253kB time=00:00:03.36 bitrate= 615.5kbits/s dup=233 drop=0 speed=0.402x
2022-09-01 18:24:31.449   frame=  110 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     309kB time=00:00:03.36 bitrate= 750.7kbits/s dup=256 drop=0 speed=0.378x
2022-09-01 18:24:32.062   frame=  111 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     315kB time=00:00:03.83 bitrate= 672.9kbits/s dup=259 drop=0 speed=0.405x
2022-09-01 18:24:32.696   frame=  122 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     371kB time=00:00:03.85 bitrate= 787.6kbits/s dup=284 drop=0 speed=0.383x
2022-09-01 18:24:33.374   frame=  130 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     410kB time=00:00:04.34 bitrate= 773.0kbits/s dup=303 drop=0 speed=0.407x
2022-09-01 18:24:33.987   frame=  139 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     475kB time=00:00:04.34 bitrate= 895.9kbits/s dup=324 drop=0 speed=0.383x
2022-09-01 18:24:34.445   frame=  146 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     508kB time=00:00:04.83 bitrate= 861.9kbits/s dup=340 drop=0 speed=0.404x
2022-09-01 18:24:35.218   frame=  153 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     540kB time=00:00:05.03 bitrate= 878.1kbits/s dup=357 drop=0 speed=0.405x
2022-09-01 18:24:35.558   frame=  163 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     580kB time=00:00:05.31 bitrate= 893.8kbits/s dup=380 drop=0 speed=0.408x
2022-09-01 18:24:36.220   frame=  167 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     609kB time=00:00:05.31 bitrate= 938.0kbits/s dup=389 drop=0 speed=0.392x
2022-09-01 18:24:36.821   frame=  172 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     630kB time=00:00:05.78 bitrate= 892.5kbits/s dup=401 drop=0 speed=0.408x
2022-09-01 18:24:37.428   frame=  179 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     666kB time=00:00:05.78 bitrate= 943.1kbits/s dup=417 drop=0 speed=0.394x
2022-09-01 18:24:37.812   frame=  185 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=30.0 size=     689kB time=00:00:06.24 bitrate= 903.2kbits/s dup=431 drop=0 speed=0.41x
2022-09-01 18:24:38.368   frame=  190 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     711kB time=00:00:06.24 bitrate= 932.5kbits/s dup=443 drop=0 speed=0.396x
2022-09-01 18:24:38.979   frame=  195 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     737kB time=00:00:06.52 bitrate= 925.4kbits/s dup=455 drop=0 speed=0.399x
2022-09-01 18:24:39.706   frame=  204 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     778kB time=00:00:06.71 bitrate= 949.8kbits/s dup=476 drop=0 speed=0.398x
2022-09-01 18:24:40.252   frame=  212 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     808kB time=00:00:07.17 bitrate= 922.8kbits/s dup=494 drop=0 speed=0.407x
2022-09-01 18:24:40.977   frame=  220 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     841kB time=00:00:07.17 bitrate= 960.6kbits/s dup=513 drop=0 speed=0.395x
2022-09-01 18:24:41.926   frame=  226 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     886kB time=00:00:07.64 bitrate= 949.8kbits/s dup=527 drop=0 speed=0.404x
2022-09-01 18:24:42.470   frame=  233 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     921kB time=00:00:07.64 bitrate= 987.4kbits/s dup=543 drop=0 speed=0.385x
2022-09-01 18:24:43.081   frame=  237 fps= 12 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     942kB time=00:00:07.66 bitrate=1007.5kbits/s dup=553 drop=0 speed=0.374x
2022-09-01 18:24:43.745   frame=  241 fps= 11 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=     971kB time=00:00:08.10 bitrate= 981.5kbits/s dup=562 drop=0 speed=0.384x
2022-09-01 18:24:44.270   frame=  248 fps= 11 q=29.0 q=33.0 size=    1011kB time=00:00:08.10 bitrate=1021.5kbits/s dup=578 drop=0 speed=0.373x
2022-09-01 18:24:45.085   frame=  251 fps= 11 q=29.0 q=30.0 size=    1031kB time=00:00:08.10 bitrate=1042.1kbits/s dup=585 drop=0 speed=0.364x

As per my knowledge we have to add such type of delay or late stream video using some command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try adding `-tune zerolatency` argument.

Comment: I have added -tune zerolatency command but it is not working